# Alternative way to rearrange objects on a stage?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

I want my menu to appear above everything else when my game opens but at the minute, the menu is on top at first until my timer starts then all of the other objects appear over the top of the menu. How can I change it so that the menu is on top and the game only starts playing and the timer only starts once the user clicks the 'Play' button and it takes them to the game?

Here is the code I have in my Main.as file. I have been experimenting to no avail as I have tried to figure out the easiest or most efficient way to do this, but I am so frustrated with it at the minute:

```
package  {
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.ui.Mouse;
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.media.SoundChannel;
import flash.text.TextFormat;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.system.LoaderContext;

public class Main extends MovieClip {

public var gameTime:int;
public var levelDuration:int;

    public var crosshair:crosshair_mc;
static var score:Number;

var enemyShipTimer:Timer;
var enemyShipTimerMed:Timer;
var enemyShipTimerSmall:Timer;
var menu:menuMain = new menuMain;

static var scoreHeader:TextField = new TextField();
static var scoreText:TextField = new TextField();
static var timeHeader:TextField = new TextField();
static var timeText:TextField = new TextField();

public function Main()
{
    levelDuration = 30;
    gameTime = levelDuration;
    var gameTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000,levelDuration);
    gameTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, updateTime);
    gameTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, timeExpired)
    gameTimer.start();


    scoreHeader = new TextField();
    scoreHeader.x = 5;
    scoreHeader.text = String("Score: ");
    addChild(scoreHeader);

    scoreText = new TextField();
    scoreText.x = 75;
    scoreText.y = 0;
    scoreText.text = String(0);
    addChild(scoreText);

    timeHeader = new TextField();
    timeHeader.x = 490;
    timeHeader.y = 0;
    timeHeader.text = String("Time: ");
    addChild(timeHeader);

    timeText = new TextField();
    timeText.x = 550;
    timeText.y = 0;
    timeText.text = gameTime.toString();
    addChild(timeText);

    var scoreFormat = new TextFormat("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 20, 0xFFFFFF);
    scoreHeader.setTextFormat(scoreFormat);
    scoreText.setTextFormat(scoreFormat);
    timeHeader.setTextFormat(scoreFormat);
    timeText.setTextFormat(scoreFormat);

    enemyShipTimer = new Timer(2000);
    enemyShipTimer.addEventListener("timer", sendEnemy);
    enemyShipTimer.start();

    enemyShipTimerMed = new Timer(2500);
    enemyShipTimerMed.addEventListener("timer", sendEnemyMed);
    enemyShipTimerMed.start();

    enemyShipTimerSmall = new Timer(2750);
    enemyShipTimerSmall.addEventListener("timer", sendEnemySmall);
    enemyShipTimerSmall.start();

    crosshair = new crosshair_mc();
    addChild(crosshair);

    crosshair.mouseEnabled = crosshair.mouseChildren = false;

    Mouse.hide();

    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveCursor);
    resetScore();
    showMenu();
}

function showMenu()
{
    stage.addChild(menu);
    Mouse.show();
    enemyShipTimer.stop();
    enemyShipTimerMed.stop();
    enemyShipTimerSmall.stop();
}

function sendEnemy(e:Event)
{
    var enemy = new EnemyShip();
    stage.addChild(enemy);
    stage.addChild(crosshair);
}

function sendEnemyMed(e:Event)
{
    var enemymed = new EnemyShipMed();
    stage.addChild(enemymed);
    stage.addChild(crosshair);
}

function sendEnemySmall(e:Event)
{
    var enemysmall = new EnemyShipSmall();
    stage.addChild(enemysmall);
    stage.addChild(crosshair);
}

static function updateScore(points)
{
    score += points;
    scoreText.text = String(score);
    var scoreFormat = new TextFormat("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 20, 0xFFFFFF);
    scoreHeader.setTextFormat(scoreFormat);
    scoreText.setTextFormat(scoreFormat);
}

static function resetScore()
{
    score = 0;
    scoreText.text = String(score);
}

function updateTime(e:TimerEvent):void
{
    trace(gameTime);
    // your class variable tracking each second, 
    gameTime--;
    //update your user interface as needed
    var scoreFormat = new TextFormat("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 20, 0xFFFFFF);
    timeText.defaultTextFormat = scoreFormat;
    timeText.text = String(gameTime);
}

function timeExpired(e:TimerEvent):void
{
    var gameTimer:Timer = e.target as Timer;
    gameTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, updateTime)
    gameTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timeExpired)
    // do whatever you need to do for game over
}

function moveCursor(event:Event) 
{
  crosshair.x=mouseX;
  crosshair.y=mouseY;
}
}
}
```

I have been trying to figure it out most of the day but I don't have a lot of experience with Actionscript.

Comment: This question has an answer I gave on this topic - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15855551/how-to-fix-overlapping-objects-on-the-stage-in-as3/15856962#15856962

Comment: I see. I'm not quite sure how I'd rearrange things though as in how to categorize things and where to move / arrange the code

Comment: Give it a try. What categories do you have ? I think that answer detailed 3 common categories, it's up to you to decide what yours are. This is not a "code my game for me" site.

Comment: This is nearly identical to the question you asked yesterday (which I provided an answer for, for both your menu issue and generic children depth swapping). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16327670/rearrange-order-of-children-on-the-stage

Answer (score 1):

Create two containers (Sprites or MovieClips), add the one that you want to be in the back first, and the one you want to be in the front second. Now, add the menu to the front one and evrything else to the back one.

Comment: Is this `DisplayObjectContainers` you're talking about? Just thought I'd double check when it comes to finding resources / examples.