# Layering objects in Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

I was wondering what was the best way to change the layering of objects in Flash? My project is made up of mostly small individual movie clips. I want to better organize my objects into layers so that one set of movieclips can be shown above another at a given time without any conflicts. Any advice on the best way to do this would be great.

EDIT: Getting errors with the following:

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.DisplayObject;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var backgroundLayer:Sprite = new Sprite;
backgroundLayer.name = "backgroundLayer";

var gameLayer:Sprite = new Sprite;
gameLayer.name = "gameLayer";

var menuLayer:Sprite = new Sprite;
menuLayer.name = "menuLayer";

public function Main()
{
    addChild(backgroundLayer);
    addChild(gameLayer);
    addChild(menuLayer);
```

Errors are:

```
1120: Access of undefined property backgroundLayer.
1120: Access of undefined property gameLayer.
1120: Access of undefined property menuLayer.
```

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15855551/how-to-fix-overlapping-objects-on-the-stage-in-as3/15856962#15856962 - this answer should help you out.

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting errors when trying to declare the layers as variables. Updated question to show this.

Comment: You can't define the name of those layers in the declarations, put the name assignments in your constructor. Also, why are you naming them? You have a variable named menuLayer that you can use.

Comment: Is this code on a timeline or a class ?I'm just giving you the basic concept of what to do, with some example code.  You changed it, and so you got errors. You created a "new" issue. If you aren't able to apply these concepts, might be good to take a step back learn a bit more about the display list and structure of a class.

Comment: The code is in a class.

Comment: I don't see a class declaration or a package definition. You need to look into the proper structure for a class. Good to know the basic structure so you know where to put your code.

Comment: http://www.untoldentertainment.com/blog/2009/08/25/tutorial-understanding-classes-in-as3-part-1/ - this link has a decent tutorial  on the subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to do this is to make a hierarchy of [`DisplayObjectContainer`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html)s or its subclasses. (`Sprite`, `MovieClip`, etc.) Once these are added to the stage in the proper order, any children of these containers will be "within" the layer of the container.

To move an object between these layers in code, you just have to `oldLayer.removeChild(thing); newLayer.addChild(thing);`.

Whether or not this is the "best" way to do this depends on what you are doing, but this is a way that I've done game object layering in the past.

Comment: Essentially I want to figure out the best way to show my menu without the other objects getting in the way (The game is a game in which UFOs are randomly generated and you have to click on them to shoot them and score a point) but since I have timers and whatnot in the game, the UFOs kept overlapping the menu and showing over the top of it. Most of the objects in my game are movieclips so when making a hierarchy of DisplayObjectContainer should I use MovieClip subclasses or doesn't it matter much?

Comment: If a class inherits from `DisplayObjectContainer` anywhere along the chain, that just means that it can contain other `DisplayObject`s. So yeah, you could use a MovieClip called "gameLayer" or something that you can addChild your UFOs onto.