# How do I move a movie clip behind a movie clip in flash?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am making a game where there are bombs and enemies. I want the enemies to move behind the bombs. These enemies are in an array called "enemies" and the bombs are in an array called "bombs" They move from the top of the screen to the bottom. Is there any type of code that can make my enemies underneath my bombs?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to fix overlapping objects on the stage in AS3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15855551/how-to-fix-overlapping-objects-on-the-stage-in-as3)

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15855551/how-to-fix-overlapping-objects-on-the-stage-in-as3/15856962#15856962 - the question could be posed hundreds of ways with different specifics and answered the same way.

Comment: @prototypical These are not exact duplicates, at least the better way of solving this issue will be Sergey Senkov's answer, instead of sorting enemies and bombs in a single display list.

Comment: @vesper Sergey's answer is the same concept as the duplicate I linked, if you read it.Each layer is a container - purely semantics. So yeah, it's a duplicate. Again, the specifics of each situation might differ, but the concept is the same. Having 50 different questions that essentially come down to having containers/layers for layering content is overkill.

Comment: I think the largest issue is that there isn't a properly worded and formed question, and all who have asked it would likely never search for it with those words if there was. So each new person that has the same problem adds a new question in their own words in the specific context of their individual game etc.

Answer (score 1):

You should add two MovieClip containers, and after that add your elements. Add enemiesContainer to stage, after that add bombContainer.

```
var enemiesContainer: MovieClip = new MovieClip();
var bombContainer: MovieClip = new MovieClip();
addChild(enemiesContainer);
addChild(bombContainer);

function addEnemy():void{
    enemiesContainer.addChild(new Enemy()); // from array
}

function addBomb():void{
    bombContainer.addChild(new Bomb()); // from array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [addChildAt(child:DisplayObject, index:int)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#addChildAt%28%29)

Assuming variables `bomb` and `enemy`, and the display list looks like this:

```
root:MaintTimeline ¬
    0: bomb:MovieClip
    1: enemy:MovieClip
```

Then running `addChildAt(enemy, 0)` will update the display list to:

```
root:MaintTimeline ¬
    0: enemy:MovieClip
    1: bomb:MovieClip
```